# Tests in React are passing if run separately but throw error when both of them are run

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, jestjs, react-testing-library

Having the following testing file:

```
import { render } from '@testing-library/react';

import '@testing-library/jest-dom';
import TaskModal from './task-modal';

describe('TaskModal', () => {
  const title = 'title';
  const selectedOption = { id: '1', name: 'test' };
  const options = [{ id: '1', name: 'test' }];
  it('should render successfully', () => {
    const { baseElement, getByText } = render(
      <TaskModal
        title={title}
        open={true}
        toggle={jest.fn()}
        initialScriptNameSelectedOption={selectedOption}
        scriptNameOptions={options}
      />
    );
    expect(baseElement).toBeTruthy();
    expect(getByText(title)).toBeTruthy();
  });

  it('should check if TaskModal renders Textarea successfully', () => {
    const { getByTestId } = render(
      <TaskModal
        hasTextarea
        title={title}
        open={true}
        toggle={jest.fn()}
        initialScriptNameSelectedOption={selectedOption}
        scriptNameOptions={options}
      />
    );
    const textarea = getByTestId('has-textarea');
    expect(textarea).toBeInTheDocument();
  });
});
```

When I run each test separately they pass, when I run the whole file, the second test fails with the following message:

> Error: Uncaught [ReferenceError: IntersectionObserver is not defined]

Why is this happening?

Comment: I might be mistaken, but I think its this line:  const textarea = getByTestId('has-textarea');

should be: const textarea = screen.getByTestId('has-textarea'); ?

Comment: same error unfortunately

Comment: Though, why do you write hasTextarea and then query it using testId? Do you write data-testid="has-textarea" in any where of your code? This might be the bug, because tests are pass when seperately because they don't spot the bug. Also, the error message `IntersectionObserver` is strange and is a sign of bug somewhere in your code, which lead to this misinformation error.